# Documentation: Can we add to the help center best practices for documentation?

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics

So I've been perusing a bunch of documentation boards and while a lot of the popular ones seem fairly well organized, I feel smaller ones tend to get really messy where people just make topics everywhere when they can easily just add the examples to a slightly broader topic. Actually I can see arguments for both cases of what might make more sense. I know there is a way to merge examples into other topics but ideally this isn't a problem in the first place.

I feel it would be good to have a how-to-document or some sort of topic similar to how we have [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center so people know what makes sense. I can understand because it's so new maybe best practices haven't been established yet but would be really good to have something to reference.

As of right now, I'm just trying to reference how some other boards have done things. Anybody have thoughts? Also if people want to post what their best practices are, I would really appreciate it.